# Is there any way to auto close the bezier tools when using the Pen tool for every new angle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using the pen tool, I can't imagine why anyone would want the following line segment to go in the ( random ? ) angle it chooses for you when making a new anchor point.

After making every line, I tediously have to go back and close the bezier by clicking on my point again to make the next line start a "fresh angle".

Is there any way to make every line do that?

I know holding the option key will give you one extra line that is clear.

I've also heard of the technique where just plot all your lines, and then go back and adjust the beziers, but that requires two clicks per dot.

Answer (score 2):

If you merely want independent, unconnected lines, use the Line Segment Tool in Illustrator.

If you are trying to create a complete shape with the pen tool, you **do not** want each segment to be an independent line. You want the lines connected. Simply click to start, click again when you wish to change direction, click-drag when you wish to create a curve.

If you want an independent Bezier curve, then you can simply click-clickDrag, then hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key down and click anywhere. Or Click-ClickDrag and then hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything.